# Tracking overall email engagement while having "DoNotTrack" enabled

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-studio, gdpr, tracking

Due to the absence of consent with regard to the tracking of user behavior related to emails, the "DoNotTrack" attribute has to be set for all contacts. This obviously prevents - first and foremost - tracking at the individual level (see clicks, opens, etc.)

Is there nevertheless the possibility to comprehend the overall success of the email with regard to the classical email KPIs (opens, clicks...) without drawing conclusions about individual engagement? For example, to create a report that email "ABC" has an open rate of 45% and a click-through rate of 3% whereas email "XYC" has an open rate of 21% and a click-through rate of 2%.

Some tools do offer such a possibility, meaning they provide statistics/KPIs for the email as a whole while having disabled tracking at the individual level, but it seems MC prevents this entirely (which might be simply compliant with GDPR) if email tracking is disabled or rather the "DoNotTrack" attribute is set.

Does anyone know if there is a way in MC to obtain these statistics or is this entirely disabled by design?

Answer (score 0):

You might try retrieving the aggregated Send object data via SOAP API with [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) in your account to see if it's populated.  Here's an example retrieve:

```
POST /Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: YOURTENANTHERE.soap.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: text/plain

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://mc-74yb-wsyrydssz9lxtysqbhv4.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">YOURTOKENHERE</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>Send</ObjectType>
                <Properties>ID</Properties>
                <Properties>Additional</Properties>
                <Properties>BCCEmail</Properties>
                <Properties>BccEmail</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.PartnerClientKey</Properties>
                <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
                <Properties>Duplicates</Properties>
                <Properties>Email.ID</Properties>
                <Properties>Email.PartnerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>EmailName</Properties>
                <Properties>EmailSendDefinition.CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>EmailSendDefinition.ObjectID</Properties>
                <Properties>ExistingUndeliverables</Properties>
                <Properties>ExistingUnsubscribes</Properties>
                <Properties>ForwardedEmails</Properties>
                <Properties>FromAddress</Properties>
                <Properties>FromName</Properties>
                <Properties>HardBounces</Properties>
                <Properties>InvalidAddresses</Properties>
                <Properties>IsAlwaysOn</Properties>
                <Properties>IsMultipart</Properties>
                <Properties>MissingAddresses</Properties>
                <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberDelivered</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberErrored</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberExcluded</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberSent</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberTargeted</Properties>
                <Properties>OtherBounces</Properties>
                <Properties>PartnerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>PreviewURL</Properties>
                <Properties>SendDate</Properties>
                <Properties>SendLimit</Properties>
                <Properties>SendWindowClose</Properties>
                <Properties>SendWindowOpen</Properties>
                <Properties>SentDate</Properties>
                <Properties>SoftBounces</Properties>
                <Properties>Status</Properties>
                <Properties>Subject</Properties>
                <Properties>UniqueClicks</Properties>
                <Properties>UniqueOpens</Properties>
                <Properties>Unsubscribes</Properties>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

If it is, you can mirror this data back into a Data Extension for reporting purposes using [this method](https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-storing-aggregated-send-data/) I've outlined on my blog.